# Format the datetime to get date and hour information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to get the date and hour information for a given datetime object in Transact-SQL?

E.g. `2014-12-18 21:00:00` for `2014-12-18 21:24:05`.

I need to truncate off all parts after the hour - i.e. minutes, seconds, and partial seconds.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, show what you tried. If not, please do so before asking for someone here to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

```
Select DATEPART(HOUR, [date]) + ":" + DATEPART(MINUTE, [date]);
```

Oracle:

```
Select TO_CHAR([date], 'HH:MI') From...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()) AS TimeOnly,
CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly
GO
```

Replace the `GETDATE()` function with whatever you need.